# Firefox issue on closing X the button

Tags: .net

When we click on closing the browser in firefox unable to get warning message....How to solve this issue.
My below code

```js
 
 <body window.onbeforeunload="bunload">

 
 function bunload() {
            dontleave = "Are you sure you want to leave?";
            return dontleave;
        }
```

---

Please solve this issue on click [X] the browser in firefox not to able to get warning message for windowbeforeunload,windowunload.

Comment: It is a popup target, ransomware is a pretty big problem these days.  Check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), note the use of dom.disable_beforeunload in Firefox.

Comment: Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome and Firefox, the user has to interact with the page. So when someone opens the page and immediately navigates away, the message will not be shown. This is true for both Chrome and Firefox. With that in mind, have a look at the code below.

```
(function () {
   window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
       var dialogText = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
       e.returnValue = dialogText;
       return dialogText;
   };
})();
```

> The function should assign a string value to the returnValue property of the Event object and return the same string.

Inspired on this article: [WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) at MDN.

Please also have a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh0t5hd8/) where you can see it actually *does* work, but only **after** the user has had any interaction with the page. Like clicking on it somewhere. This is probably because they don't want pages to try and keep users from navigating away if they haven't even interacted with the page.

Comment: @prajna please ask one question per post. If you have further questions, please ask a new question. Deal only with the issue you have asked in your question here.